# Reading and searching datas from binary file

Tags: c++

in my lab work we gotta read datas from txt and write them to .dat file as a binary format, then we should search and find datas by given id in binary file.
Our `worker.txt` file in this

**format:**

```
ID firstname lastname age salary
```

like:

```
341 Alex Morgan 32 3400
234 Jessica Gibson 28 2000
...
```

Program reads these datas then writes all of them to worker.dat as a binary file.

The problem is when entered valid Id for searching program find and print it but then close with windows stopped execution error, I need your help to handle it.

**My searchByID function:**

```
void searchByID( int key )
{
bool find=false;
int id,age,sal;
string fn,ln;
ifstream InFile;
InFile.open("worker.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
int i = getSize( initialArr );
int j;
for( j=0; j<i; j++ ){
    InFile.read( (char*)&id, sizeof(int));
    InFile.read( (char*)&fn, sizeof(string));
    InFile.read( (char*)&ln, sizeof(string));
    InFile.read( (char*)&age, sizeof(int));
    InFile.read( (char*)&sal, sizeof(int));
    if( id == key )
    {
        cout << "Datas for Entered ID:\n"
            << id <<" "<< fn <<" "
            << ln <<" "<< age <<" "
            << sal << endl;
        find = true;
    }
}
if( !find )
    cout << "Entered ID not Found on File" << endl;
InFile.close();
}
```

Comment: This is a text file not a binary file.

Comment: You describe the format of `worker.txt` but not the format of `worker.dat`

Comment: Firstly program reads datas from txt file then writes all informations to binary file, you can reach binary file from this link: http://www.speedyshare.com/97mth/worker.dat

Comment: @Hogan I'm guessing the byte layout of worker.dat is pretty close to the code he's currently having issues with. It would obviously help to see the **writer** code.

Comment: @WhozCraig does that mean the strings are null terminated?

Comment: @Hogan that would entirely be dependent on how that writer code was implemented (which remains a mystery). I know *I* wouldn't do it that way. I would burn a uint32_t into the output byte stream as a length-prefix, then send the characters in afterward, for every char buffer type. Terminator would be optional since you can always add it yourself on the read.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Exactly my unstated point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing something like this isn't going to work:

```
InFile.read( (char*)&fn, sizeof(string));
```

A string usually internally contains a pointer to the actual characters, so the actual text wouldn't be stored in the file anywhere.   You would need to use a char array to read and write your strings instead.

Comment: +1 He should also be using known-width values (uint32_t, etc.) and ideally network-ordering them before the write, de-ordering them on the read, unless there is no interest whatsoever in portability.

Comment: Thank you for answering after changed all strings to char array program worked.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a number of problems here, as I said in the comments you are describing the format of worker.txt and reading from a file called worker.dat.  Are they the same format?  If not then you are reading a text file.  If so then you don't know the length of the strings -- but I would guess they are null terminated.

Here is an example of one of your problems -- sizeof(string) will always be the size of the pointer not the length of the string you are reading.

If this is a text file what you want to do is this:

- Read a line from the text file.
- Parse that line